# Preserve space coming in data in XSLT

Tags: c#, xml, vb.net, xslt

I have data coming like this

```
<Table1>
 <row_description>Low Touch</row_description>
 <_x0038_ />
 <_x0039_ />
 <_x0031_0 />
 <_x0031_1 />
 <_x0031_2 />
</Table1>
<Table1>
 <row_description>    DMA/ALGO</row_description>
 <_x0038_ />
 <_x0039_ />
 <_x0031_0 />
 <_x0031_1 />
 <_x0031_2 />
</Table1>
<Table1>
 <row_description>    PT</row_description>
 <_x0038_ />
 <_x0039_ />
 <_x0031_0 />
 <_x0031_1 />
 <_x0031_2 />
</Table1>
```

and my XSLT does this

```
<xsl:for-each select="*">
    <TableCell Padding="10,1" BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" BorderBrush="#FF888888">
        <xsl:if test="position()=1">
            <Paragraph>
                <Span>
                    <Run>
                      <xsl:value-of select="text()" />
                    </Run>
                </Span>
            </Paragraph>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="position()>1">
            <Paragraph TextAlignment="Right">
                <Span>
                    <Run>
                        <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
                    </Run>
                </Span>
            </Paragraph>
        </xsl:if>
    </TableCell>
</xsl:for-each>
```

but it is removing space coming before my text `PT` to `PT`. How to preserve space coming in data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am OP and I did this to overcome my problem

```
<Run xml:space="preserve"><xsl:value-of select="text()" /></Run>
```

**Note:** After writing `xml:space="preserve"`, please make sure `<xsl:value-of select="text()" />`is in the same line. If we write like this

```
<Run xml:space="preserve">
    <xsl:value-of select="text()" />
</Run>
```

it will also consider the indentation of xsl as text as we have said to preserve space.

Answer (score 2):

In your XSLT make use of:

```
<xsl:preserve-space elements="*" />
```

See: http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/el_preserve-space.asp

---

When I have the following input XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data>
    <Table1>
        <row_description>Low Touch</row_description>
        <_x0038_/>
        <_x0039_/>
        <_x0031_0/>
        <_x0031_1/>
        <_x0031_2/>
    </Table1>
    <Table1>
        <row_description>    DMA/ALGO</row_description>
        <_x0038_/>
        <_x0039_/>
        <_x0031_0/>
        <_x0031_1/>
        <_x0031_2/>
    </Table1>
    <Table1>
        <row_description>    PT</row_description>
        <_x0038_/>
        <_x0039_/>
        <_x0031_0/>
        <_x0031_1/>
        <_x0031_2/>
    </Table1>
</data>
```

And I use the following XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:preserve-space elements="*" />

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Table1">
        <xsl:for-each select="*">
            <TableCell Padding="10,1" BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" BorderBrush="#FF888888">
                <xsl:if test="position()=1">
                    <Paragraph>
                        <Span>
                            <Run>
                              <xsl:value-of select="text()" />
                            </Run>
                        </Span>
                    </Paragraph>
                </xsl:if>
                <xsl:if test="position()>1">
                    <Paragraph TextAlignment="Right">
                        <Span>
                            <Run>
                                <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
                            </Run>
                        </Span>
                    </Paragraph>
                </xsl:if>
            </TableCell>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The output shows as expected:

```
<TableCell Padding="10,1" BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" BorderBrush="#FF888888">
    <Paragraph><Span><Run>Low Touch</Run>
        </Span></Paragraph>
</TableCell>
<TableCell Padding="10,1" BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" BorderBrush="#FF888888">
    <Paragraph TextAlignment="Right"><Span><Run></Run>
        </Span></Paragraph>
</TableCell>
<TableCell Padding="10,1" BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" BorderBrush="#FF888888">
    <Paragraph TextAlignment="Right"><Span><Run></Run>
        </Span></Paragraph>
</TableCell>
<TableCell Padding="10,1" BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" BorderBrush="#FF888888">
    <Paragraph TextAlignment="Right"><Span><Run></Run>
        </Span></Paragraph>
</TableCell>
<TableCell Padding="10,1" BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" BorderBrush="#FF888888">
    <Paragraph TextAlignment="Right"><Span><Run></Run>
        </Span></Paragraph>
</TableCell>
<TableCell Padding="10,1" BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" BorderBrush="#FF888888">
    <Paragraph TextAlignment="Right"><Span><Run></Run>
        </Span></Paragraph>
</TableCell>
<TableCell Padding="10,1" BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" BorderBrush="#FF888888">
    <Paragraph><Span><Run>    DMA/ALGO</Run>
        </Span></Paragraph>
</TableCell>
<TableCell Padding="10,1" BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" BorderBrush="#FF888888">
    <Paragraph TextAlignment="Right"><Span><Run></Run>
        </Span></Paragraph>
</TableCell>
<TableCell Padding="10,1" BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" BorderBrush="#FF888888">
    <Paragraph TextAlignment="Right"><Span><Run></Run>
        </Span></Paragraph>
</TableCell>
<TableCell Padding="10,1" BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" BorderBrush="#FF888888">
    <Paragraph TextAlignment="Right"><Span><Run></Run>
        </Span></Paragraph>
</TableCell>
<TableCell Padding="10,1" BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" BorderBrush="#FF888888">
    <Paragraph TextAlignment="Right"><Span><Run></Run>
        </Span></Paragraph>
</TableCell>
<TableCell Padding="10,1" BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" BorderBrush="#FF888888">
    <Paragraph TextAlignment="Right"><Span><Run></Run>
        </Span></Paragraph>
</TableCell>
<TableCell Padding="10,1" BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" BorderBrush="#FF888888">
    <Paragraph><Span><Run>    PT</Run>
        </Span></Paragraph>
</TableCell>
<TableCell Padding="10,1" BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" BorderBrush="#FF888888">
    <Paragraph TextAlignment="Right"><Span><Run></Run>
        </Span></Paragraph>
</TableCell>
<TableCell Padding="10,1" BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" BorderBrush="#FF888888">
    <Paragraph TextAlignment="Right"><Span><Run></Run>
        </Span></Paragraph>
</TableCell>
<TableCell Padding="10,1" BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" BorderBrush="#FF888888">
    <Paragraph TextAlignment="Right"><Span><Run></Run>
        </Span></Paragraph>
</TableCell>
<TableCell Padding="10,1" BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" BorderBrush="#FF888888">
    <Paragraph TextAlignment="Right"><Span><Run></Run>
        </Span></Paragraph>
</TableCell>
<TableCell Padding="10,1" BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" BorderBrush="#FF888888">
    <Paragraph TextAlignment="Right"><Span><Run></Run>
        </Span></Paragraph>
</TableCell>
```

The value `<Run>    PT</Run>` still has the spaces in it. As XSLT processor I used Altova XMLSpy.

Comment: Did that. problem is same. I added it here `<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:preserve-space elements="*" />`

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal that is strange. I updated my answer with an example XSLT. And example input and output. As you can see the spaces are preserved. Maybe the problem lies in your XSLT processor?